# understanding iptables filtering on two virtualbox guests

Tags: networking, virtualbox, iptables

I have 2 virtualbox guests, each with ONLY an internal network (192.168.68.0/24). They can ping each other, and tcpdump shows no other traffic on the only interfaces (enp0s8) active on both boxes. I have iptables rules loaded on BOX-B that will ACCEPT and LOG traffic sent from BOX-A to BOX-B with a source of 192.168.68.0/24 and destination of 192.168.68.0/24. I have verified this and the LOG message displays in /var/log/messages.

I have another iptables rule that REJECTS and LOGS traffic sourced from 172.16.0.0/16 with a destination of 172.30.0.0/16. I have a route on BOX-A that sends traffic destined for 172.30.0.0/16 via dev enp0s8.

When I send a packet (src=172.16.1.1, dst=172.30.1.1) using  python/scapy tcpdump on BOX-B shows that the packet arrived, but /var/log/messages doesn't show the REJECT LOG, and the iptables counter for the rule doesn't increment.

What am I missing?